# Jackson DeSerialize Class with <T> (Generic) Type

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Can any one help me to know the right way to convert this POJO to json using Jackson ?
how can i get the wright type of this class to pass it to  `readValue(content, valueType)` ?

thank you.

```
public class GcmMessages<T> {

    int mType;
    int mEmpId;
    Date mDate;
    T[] mBody;

    public GcmMessages()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is probably a [`TypeReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

```
final TypeReference<GcmMessage<Foo>> typeref
    = new TypeReference<GcmMessage<Foo>>(){};

final GcmMessage<Foo> = mapper.readValue(yourSource, typeref);
```

Not sure how it handles "generic arrays" however, never had to try that.

Comment: thanks, but I'v to handles generic arrays, I used to do it using GSON .

Comment: As I said, I didn't have to do that -- meaning I don't know whether it works. Knowing Jackson in general, it probably will however.